# Prevent firefox users from being able to scroll

Tags: html, css

I have noticed that when I use "overflow-x: hidden" to hide horizontal scroll bars and prevent manual scrolling, that I can still scroll using arrow keys in Mozilla Firefox (this probably happens for mouse wheel as well but I don't have a mouse wheel to test it with).

In Google chrome hiding the scroll bars does prevent scrolling, which is the behavior I want because I want to control horizontal scrolling entirely with javascript.

How can I prevent the user from controlling the scrolling across all browsers?

Here is an example jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tDzpm/3/

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I don't want the user to be able to scroll left and right in that fiddle.

Comment: Please put together a jsFiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to do it so that I can use javascript to control the scrolling.  That helps fix the problem, but it doesn't answer why this happens in Mozilla but not in Chrome.  I am looking for a deeper understanding of the system as well as solution.

Comment: Hiding scroll bars also won't prevent scrolling on tablets and other touchscreen devices.

Answer (score 2):

`overflow: hidden` only hides the scrollbars. Page Down/Up, arrow keys, and the mouse wheel still work. See the [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) question on Stack Overflow on how to disable them.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it by using Javascript to overwrite the default-functionality of the arrow keys.

I added a simple JQuery function, which should be called at 'the end' of the site/pageload-cycle (e.g. in a script-tag like)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("html").keydown(function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 32://space
        case 33://pgup
        case 34://pgdn
        case 35://end
        case 36://home
        case 37://left
        case 38://up
        case 39://right
        case 40://down
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This won't prevent other methods of scrolling, such as the mouse wheel and other driver-specific implementations. Plus it's simply a bad experience to override the functions of common keyboard commands. What if the user is disabled and can only use a keyboard to navigate?

Comment: that would really be too bad, but i dont see why the other method shouldn't 'block' disabled users too?